# Axios.get returns junk html for react app deployed on Vercel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, axios, vercel

Here is the link to the repository -> [spoon-fed](https://github.com/Mayank-Jain-1/SpoonFed.github.io)

I have my front end of my website being hosted on vercel.

I am unable get fetch axios.get requests to my backend server also hosted on Vercel. The Backend is working great i have tested individual apis using VS Code Thunder Client. Deployed at https://spoon-fed-server.vercel.app/

I have added the `"proxy": "https://spoon-fed-server.vercel.app/"` in the package.json file of my frontend.

```js
function App() {
   const dispatch = useDispatch();

   useEffect(() => {
      axios
         .get("/api/allRestaurants")
         .then((res) => {
            dispatch(updateRestaurant(res.data));
            console.log("restaurant data fetched succesfully");
            // dispatch(updateFilteredRestaurants(res.data));
         })
         .catch((err) => console.log(err));
      console.log("couldnt fetch the restaurant data");
      eslint-disable-next-line
   }, []);
```

This is what is returned when made an axios.get request in the above code.

```js
filteredRestaurants:  "<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com"/><link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin/><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/><meta charset="utf-8"/><link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/><meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app"/><link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png"/><link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/><title>Spoon Fed</title><script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.d86bc55d.js"></script><link href="/static/css/main.b4b38051.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div></body></html>"
```

This causes app crash due to functions like `filteredRestaurants.map`  on the variable in this part of the code

```js
export const SearchHeader = () => {

  const city = useSelector(store => store.searchInputs.city);
  const searchValue = useSelector(store => store.searchInputs.search);

  const restaurant = useSelector((store) => store.restaurants);

  const filter = (city, search ) => {
    let filteredRes = restaurant;
    if(filteredRes.length > 0){
      if(city){
        filteredRes = filteredRes?.filter(restaurant => restaurant.city_name.toLowerCase() === city.toLowerCase());
      }
      if(search){
        filteredRes = filteredRes?.filter(restaurant => restaurant.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()))
      }
    }
    return filteredRes;
  }
  const filteredRestaurants = filter(city,searchValue);
  console.log('filteredRestaurants: ', filteredRestaurants);
```

I tried making the api call from the vercel deployed project. The api request are working in the development localhost:3000 but not on the deployed version.